# Payroll in java is resulting 0

Tags: java, eclipse

The problem is:

Design a Payroll class that has fields for an employee's name, ID number, hourly pay rate, and number of hours worked. Write the appropriate accessor and mutator methods abd a constructor that accepts the employee's name and ID number as agruments. The class should also have a method that returns the employee's gross pay, which is calculate as the number of hours worked multiplied by the hourly pay rate. Write a program that demonstrates the class by creating a Payroll objectm then asking the user to enter the data for an employee. The program should display the amount of gross pay earned.
Heres what I have for the class

```
import java.util.Scanner;   //Needed for scanner class.
public class Payroll
{
    private String EmployeeName;
    private int IDnumber;
    private double HourlyPayRate;
    private double HoursWorked;
    private double GrossPay;

    /**
        Constructor
        @param Name The name to store in EmployeeName.
        @param ID The ID to store in Employee ID number.
    */
    public Payroll(String Name, int ID)
    {
        EmployeeName = Name;
        IDnumber = ID;
    }
    public String getEmployeeName()
    {
        return EmployeeName;
    }
    public int getIDnumber()
    {
        return IDnumber;
    }
    public void setHourlyPayRate(double HourlyRate)
    {
        HourlyPayRate = HourlyRate;
    }
    public double getHourlyPayRate()
    {
        return HourlyPayRate;
    }
    public void setHoursWorked(double hoursWorked)
    {
        HoursWorked = hoursWorked;
    }
    public double getHoursWorked()
    {
        return HoursWorked;
    }
    public double getGrossPay()
    {
        return HourlyPayRate * HoursWorked;
    }
}
```

The constructor

```
import java.util.Scanner;   //Needed for Scanner class.

public class PayrollTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String EmployeeName;
        int IDnumber;
        double HoursWorked;
        double HourlyPayRate;
        double GrossPay;

        //Create a Scanner object for keyboard input.
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Get the employee's name.
        System.out.println("Enter an employee's name: ");
        EmployeeName = keyboard.nextLine();

        //Get the employee's ID.
        System.out.println("Enter the employee's ID " );
        IDnumber = keyboard.nextInt();

        //Get the number of hours worked by the employee.
        System.out.println("Enter the amount of hours worked by this employee: ");
        HoursWorked = keyboard.nextDouble();

        //Get the hourly pay rate of the employee.
        System.out.println("Enter the hourly pay rate for this employee: ");
        HourlyPayRate = keyboard.nextDouble();

        //Create a payroll object, passing EmployeeName and IDnumber
        // as arguments to the constructor.
        Payroll pay = new Payroll(EmployeeName, IDnumber);

        //Get the Gross Pay of the employee.
        System.out.println("The gross pay of " + EmployeeName + " is: " + pay.getGrossPay());
    }
}
```

When I compile it, I didn't get any error but i keep getting the result of grosspay = 0.0 at the end.

Comment: Few of us here will check your homework for you. I suggest you cut this down to the absolute minimum to demonstrate your issue. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create a new `Payroll` object

```
Payroll pay = new Payroll(EmployeeName, IDnumber);
```

and call the `getGrossPay()` method on it in your print statement

```
pay.getGrossPay()
```

that method does the following:

```
return HourlyPayRate * HoursWorked;
```

since you never set `HourlyPayRate` or `HoursWorked`, of course the method is going to return 0.

To fix this, set those values to the variables you read from the user:

```
pay.setHoursWorked(HoursWorked);
pay.setHourlyPayRate(HourlyPayRate);
```

You can add those lines after you create the `Payroll` object but before you call the `getGrossPay()` method. So the last four lines of your code should now look like this:

```
Payroll pay = new Payroll(EmployeeName, IDnumber);

//set pay rate and hours worked
pay.setHoursWorked(HoursWorked);
pay.setHourlyPayRate(HourlyPayRate);

//Get the Gross Pay of the employee.
System.out.println("The gross pay of " + EmployeeName + " is: " + pay.getGrossPay());
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate it :D !!

Comment: Hi @JessicaLim. You can show your appreciation by upvoting and/or accepting this answer!

Comment: @JessicaLim happy to help!